# windows 10 notification - OpenJDK Platform Binary

Tags: java, windows-10, awt

I made a Windows 10 notification using the Eclipse IDE. I can't seem to get rid of the "OpenJDK Platform Binary" which shows whenever the notification pops up. I tried "MessageType.NONE" but it's still there.

Note: I can only solve this problem using Java.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType;

public class notif {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        notif td = new notif();
        td.notifDisplay();
    }
        public void notifDisplay() throws AWTException {
            SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

            Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("icon.png");

            TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(img, "pepsi");
            trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
            trayIcon.setToolTip("pepsi");
            tray.add(trayIcon);

            trayIcon.displayMessage("we are out of pepsi", ":(", MessageType.NONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, did you find any solution

Comment: no i didnt find a solution :/ i ended up just leaving it